# Nested gradle git commands

Tags: git, gradle, groovy

I want to create a commandline gradle function that will allow me to run nested git commands

for example

```
def nestedCommand(){

   exec{
       commandLine "git", "commit" "-am", "`git describe -g`"
    }

}
```

What do I need to do to make it work? The syntax is incorrect

Comment: A single `exec` invocation runs a single command, so you'll need multiple `exec` invocations or `Exec` tasks.

Answer (score 0):

See (here)[https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-achive-bash-like-functionality-e-g-ls-grep-mystuff-with-gradle-project-exec/5516]

Example:

```
task featuresWaiting(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "bash", "-c", "'${task.project.projectDir}/show.sh' | grep \-\-\- | grep #feature''
}
```

So your problem should be solved by

```
task commit(type: Exec) {
    commandLine "git", "commit", "-am", "'git describe -g'"
}
```

Comment: You mean by `commandLine 'bash', '-c', 'git commit -am `git describe -g`' ?`

Comment: I had missed a comma (fixed), else I mean exactly what I wrote. But your version may also work.